# (regular expression) How to remove quotation and whats inside all together in python?

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to remove strings in a file (a code file in which all strings are quotations) like this:

```
text = "Hello,"+Tom+"have a nice day!"
text2 = "Thank"+"you."
```

I want this (not just quotas but everything that's inside):

```
['text', 'Tom','text2']
```

I could achieve getting every string using regular expressions, and its read line by line:

```
readLine = re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9]*", line)
# there is some trimming I didn't show
```

But the result is:

```
['text','Hello','Tom','have', 'a', 'nice', 'day', 'text2', 'Thank', 'you']
```

If regex is not suitable, what are other ways? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your own words, when you use `re.findall`, what do you think `findall` means? Now, try looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents) for the `re` module. Do you see a function described that corresponds to what you want to do with the input line?

Comment: I believe your are trying to make a list of strings. Try this `my_texts = [text, text2]`

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://ideone.com/Gyy8TY

Comment: @Thefourthbird This actually works for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookahead in your regex, like this:
`[a-zA-z0-9]+(?=( = ))`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
import re
 
expr = r'"(?:[^"\\]|\\[\s\S])*"|(\w+)'
text = r'''text = "Hello,"+Tom+"have a nice day!"
           text2 = "Thank"+"you."'''
print(list(filter(None,re.findall(expr, text))))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##RY6xDoIwFEX3fsXzLS2WMOhmYlydXGSjmDTyDI2lJaUqJPw7AjHxTne45@S2Q6y920@TaVofIgRiwKhvAxwhcBSnQ3FDpcpRqUJ16lomWxyF@siEs0h9XGec/yqeyVqfosx9I7HWbwINztwJKj1skME/C7FbkLzW7okSB//KcFaxNhgXhTVdFA9jIwVx8Y7SQNnDuEpbK5Z/6WpI5jAG0/QF)

**Results:** `['text', 'Tom', 'text2']`

**Regex explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"\\]                   any character except: '"', '\\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s\S]                   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
re.findall(r'".*"',line)
```

You can simply trim the extra quotes at the beginning and end

**Edit:**
To trim it you can use

```py
[ match[1:-1] for match in re.findall(r'".*"',line) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, that is all you need:

```
re.findall('"(.*)"', sentence)
```